# Read globalChannelMap from destination template

Tags: mirth

I have a source connection reading and constructing my output all in javascript in the channel source.

I need to pass this along to access it from the destination.

So I use

```
globalChannelMap.put('fullMessage', fullMessage);
```

Inside the destination in the template window for File Writer I have

```
${fullMessage}
```

But it writes exactly that to the file. I want everything inside that variable to be written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use intermediate variables, like:

```
var data = ${fullMessage};
var fullMessage = DateUtil.convertDate('dd/MM/yyyy', 'yyyyMMdd', $('data'));
globalChannelMap.put('${fullMessage}',fullMessage);
```